# Xml FIle generation using Rythm Template Engine

Tags: rythm

I am trying to generate an xml file using rythm template and wondering if there is a way to drop few tags based on business logic.
Eg: Discard @error_message tag in case of a successful method execution.

Please help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@if](http://rythmengine.org/doc/directive.md#if) directive:

```
@ifNot(success) {
    @error_message()
}
```

Comment: How do I accept the answer? can you please let me know?

Comment: There should be a tick at the left of the answer, click it to accept the answer. If you still don't know how, check out this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgzxlwfxyujaz3b/how-to-accept-stackoverflow-answer.png?dl=0

Comment: Sure, will do asap.  Can you please help me with the other question i asked?

Comment: Sorry which question? Can you post the link here?